# Can't read data from text file written by c program

Tags: c, file

I am trying to write the number of packets I get to a textfile:

```
printf("TCP : %d   UDP : %d   ICMP : %d   IGMP : %d   Others : %d   Total : %d\r", tcp , udp , icmp , igmp , others , total);
if (usePacketCount == 1){
    fprintf(stderr,"Saving packet count");
    fprintf(packetCountFile,"TCP : %d   UDP : %d   ICMP : %d   IGMP : %d   Others : %d   Total : %d\r", tcp , udp , icmp , igmp , others , total);
}
```

When I run the program, I clearly get to this point in the code:
[image]

However when I try to read the textfile, there is nothing present:

[image]

I define my file here:

```
FILE *packetCountFile = 0;

if (usePacketCount == 1){
    printf("Using Packet Count File");
    packetCountFile = fopen("packetCount.txt","w");
}
```

I am not sure why this is failing. It may be due to the write being in a loop, and it simply can't keep up?

Comment: Does `fopen` succeed or does it return `NULL`?

Comment: Please provide a small, complete program which exhibits this behavior. Also, please check for success of all of your (important) I/O operations: `fopen()`, `fprintf()` etc. Also, please don't use screeshots of text; you can very easily copy the relevant textual output.

Comment: Looks like it _does_ print to the file, but since there's no newline at the end but a carriage return, the text editor shows many characters exist but not a single line and no content.

Comment: Why are you writing `\r` instead of `\n`? 898,964 characters doesn't seem empty.

Comment: @Yun: But then she would see the characters from the last printing, as `\r` doesn't clear the line, it only returns the carriage.

Comment: @Yun fopen does not return NULL

Comment: @einpoklum But since there's no newline, a text editor is not obliged to recognize the content as a line of text (assuming POSIX). Since there's no single line, it may not display anything.

Comment: Don't use an editor to view the file, use `more`, `less`, `xxd` or `cat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, always check the return values of `fopen` and `fprintf` for failure. Second, the text editor shows 0 lines and 898964 characters. This *is* something.

*What happened?*

The format string given to `fprintf` ends with a carriage return character (`\r`), which causes `fprintf` to write and repeatedly overwrite the first line.

*Okay, but why doesn't that first line appear in the text editor?*

This depends on the system and text editor, but what probably happens is that the text editor displays lines of text. [POSIX defines](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_206) a line as follows

> A sequence of zero or more non-<newline> characters plus a terminating <newline> character.

Since `fprintf` did not print a newline character, the file technically did not contain a single line.
Some text editors are more lenient with this than others and may actually show some contents.

Your question: *"It may be due to the write being in a loop, and it simply can't keep up?"*

If the system couldn't keep up, you'd expect `fprintf` to fail or for the writing to be slow.

*How do I solve this?*

Replace the carriage return character (`\r`) with a newline character (`\n`), which is probably what you meant to write in the first place.